# How can I associate an IAM OIDC Identity Provider with an EKS cluster with CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I can't figure out how to replicate the functionality of the "Associate Identity Provider" button on AWS console screen pictured below with CDK.

[image]

Comment: Did you figure it out how do it ?

Comment: @Maciej Unfortunately, no. However, it turned out that I didn't need it for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to specify it, it is made automatically

exemple of Go CDK code

```
func SetKubernetesCluster(stack constructs.Construct) *awseks.Cluster {

    cluster := awseks.NewCluster(stack, jsii.String("nft"), &awseks.ClusterProps{
        ClusterName:         jsii.String("nft"),
        Version:             awseks.KubernetesVersion_V1_21(),
        OutputClusterName:   jsii.Bool(true),
        OutputConfigCommand: jsii.Bool(true),
    })


    awscdk.NewCfnOutput(stack, jsii.String("OIDC-issuer"), &awscdk.CfnOutputProps{
        Value: cluster.ClusterOpenIdConnectIssuer(),
    })
    awscdk.NewCfnOutput(stack, jsii.String("OIDC-endpoint-url"), &awscdk.CfnOutputProps{
        Value: cluster.ClusterOpenIdConnectIssuerUrl(),
    })

    return &cluster
}
```